# Using "Boolean" as the argument to .filter() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, boolean

Recently I've learned that you can use the `Boolean` keyword to check whether a boolean value is `false`, e.g. this, where the  `arrayOfSheeps` is simply an array of boolean values.

```js
function countSheeps(arrayOfSheeps) {
  return arrayOfSheeps.filter(Boolean).length;
}
```

As I've been unable to find anything about using 'Boolean' as a keyword, I was wondering if there are any other uses for the word, or even just any resources I can use to learn about it.

Comment: A search for `javascript Boolean` returned the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

Comment: Where have you learnt that? `Boolean` is not a keyword!

Comment: I suppose I was using the wrong terminology, excuse my ignorance, like I said, I'm new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`Boolean` is not a keyword, it is a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean), and functions are just objects, that you can pass around. It is the same as:

```
return arrayOfSheeps.filter(function(x){return Boolean(x)}).length;
```

Since `function(x){return f(x)} === f` then you can simplify:

```
return arrayOfSheeps.filter(Boolean).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [MDN Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean),

> Do not use a Boolean object to convert a non-boolean value to a
> boolean value. To perform this task, instead, use Boolean as a
> function

```
var x = Boolean(expression);     // use this...
var x = !!(expression);          // ...or this
var x = new Boolean(expression); // don't use this!
```

So the code is same as:

```
const b = v => !!v;
arrayOfSheeps.filter(b).length;
arrayOfSheeps.filter(v => !!v).length;  // or inline
```