# what is the boolean parameter passed to the filter method?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to practice some javascript so I did some coding challenges everything went well except that I run into a problem with a challenge that says that I should create a function which returns the number of true values there are in an array.

example:

```
countTrue([true, false, false, true, false]) ➞ 2
```

I solved the challenge with the filter() method and everything is Ok and here's what I did to solve it

```
function countTrue(arr) {
var s=0;
arr.filter((i)=>{
if  (i=== true) {s++}
})
return s
}
```

but there's a shorter solution which is this:

```
const countTrue = r => r.filter(Boolean).length
```

I understood everything except that `Boolean` parameter which was passed to the filter method, I did a research about the filter() but I didn't find anything useful.
please If somebody knows the answer, enlighten me and thank you in advance.

Comment: Open your browser console.  Type `Boolean(true)` and `Boolean(false)`.  What are the results?

Comment: Part of the confusion is because you're using `filter` incorrectly in your first solution.

Comment: Here is the same topic discussed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29358815/using-boolean-as-the-argument-to-filter-in-javascript

Comment: I don't think the linked answer covers the confusion. Look at the unused `var trues`. That his filtered array is always empty, and he's using `filter` like `forEach`. This probably is a duplicate of something, but not of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29358815/using-boolean-as-the-argument-to-filter-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `Boolean` is a function that returns true if the "thing in the array is truthy" and return false if the "thing in the array is falsy"

When you call `filter` every array element will have `Boolean(the element)` called on it and the result determines if the element makes it into the output array. Your array only has values `true` and `false` and `Boolean()` will return true for your `true` values and false for your `false` values. The result is the falses are filtered out.

`Boolean()` will also return true for non boolean values like `1` or `"a"`, and false for non boolean non-values like `null` or `undefined`, so this approach would filter

```
[true, false, 1, "a", {}, null, undefined]
```

To

```
[true, 1, "a", {}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Every value in the array will be passed to the `Boolean()` object wrapper, and it will `cast (convert)` values to `true` or `false`.

This is the same as:

```js
const countTrue = r => r.filter(item => Boolean(item)).length

// Boolean(true) is true
// Boolean(false) is false
// Boolean(123) is true
// Boolean(0) is false
```

From [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean):

> The value passed as the first parameter is converted to a boolean value, if necessary. If the value is omitted or is 0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined, or the empty string (""), the object has an initial value of false. All other values, including any object, an empty array ([]), or the string "false", create an object with an initial value of true.